# Need help getting variables to stack while using tkinter buttons

Tags: python, tkinter, button

Im trying to get a count going based off of how many times you've clicked the button but it keeps resetting the variable to zero when I click the button. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Here is my code

```
import tkinter as tk

a=0

root = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='red')
frame.place(relx=0.1,rely=.1, relwidth=.8, relheight=.5)

def step_up(a):
    a=a+1
    motor1_label['text']=a
    
motor1_label = tk.Label(frame)
motor1_label.place(relx=.0,rely=.4375, relwidth=.25, relheight=.0625)

MT1 = tk.Button(frame, text="step up", bg='light grey', fg='black',command=lambda: step_up(a))  
MT1.place(relx=0, rely=.5, relwidth=0.25, relheight=0.25)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You shouldnt pass in `a`, as globalized `a` is always 0.

Comment: Can you explain a little more? I'm new to this and trying to figure it out. I've tried changing step_up(a) to step_up() in both locations and it gives me this error "local variable 'a' referenced before assignment"

Comment: `global a` will fix it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `step_up` to:

```
def step_up():
    global a
    a=a+1
    motor1_label['text']=a
```

`global a` tells python that `a` is a global variable, not a local variable. Now when you add 1 to `a`, you are changing the value of the global variable `a`.
 Passing `a` to the function will not work because it passes 0 to the function, not the variable `a`, and 0+1 will always be 1 so the counter will never go up.